# Delete form data not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My function jQuery include on my head html

```
$(function() {
$(".deletePage").click(function() {
    var pageId = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "delete_page.php",
        cache: false,               
        data:'id=' + pageId,
        success: function(response){                        
        try{        
            if(response=='true'){
                parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
            }                               
        }catch(e) {     
            alert('Exception while request..');
        }       
        },
        error: function(){                      
            alert('Error while request..');
        }
     });
    }
   }
```

And my html with listPage

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>title page</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>URL</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Edit</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Delete</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php 
                            while($row_Q = mysql_fetch_array($sql_Q)){
                         ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row_Q["title"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row_Q["permalink"]; ?></td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                <a class="deletePage" href="#">Delete</a>
                            </button>
                        </td>         
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Why not working jQuery and not delete selected page?Any help me please?I want that click on the button "DELETE" the row its delete without going other page

thank you

Comment: Have you tried `data: {'id' : pageId}`?

Comment: Is `parent` defined before `$.ajax()` call ? , or within `success` callback ? Is `alert()` called ?

Comment: Yes, I tried data: {'id' : pageId}

Comment: parent is defined now before $.ajax() but no working...

Comment: add id field to your html first.because javascript needs identifier id to work on particular html tag or field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error. You're trying to get the page ID, but it doesn't exist in your HTML code.
Add the ID to your `<a>` and you're set.

Comment: Where add the id in <a>?in href?

Comment: Something like this: `<a class="deletePage" id="your-id" href="#">`

Comment: nothing....not workink... `<a class="deletePage" id="<?php echo $row_Q['id']; ?>" href="#">Borrar</a>`

Answer (score 1):

I fix the problem :)
You said to me that add the Id to me  and yes this is a one problem but I have more problems.

This is my new function in jQuery

```
$(function() {
$(".deletePage").click(function() {
    var pageId = $(this).attr("id");
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if(confirm("Delete me?")){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:  "delete_page.php",
            cache: false,               
            data: 'id=' + pageId,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(response){
            location.reload();                      
            try{        
                if(response=='true'){
                    parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                }                   

            }catch(e) {     
                alert('Exception while request..');
            }       
            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
         });
    }
return false;
});
```

});